# Arrow function question for Dotnet framework

Tags: .net, lambda

```
 public IEnumerable<Category> AllCategories => new List<Category>
    {
        //repository: retrieves data from model class

        new Category{CategoryId=1, CategoryName="Fruit Pies", Description="All Fruity Pies"  },

        new Category {CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Cheese Cakes", Description = "Cheesey cakes"},

        new Category

    };
}
```

}

What does Arrow function mean in this context? In My eyes I just think it refers to the AllCategories object equaling a new list of Category objects.

Answer (score 0):

`AllCategories` is a read-only property whose value is the expression following the arrow.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) for more explanations.